# Помогите расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания:

> ​Было тяжело сестра умерла и уехала девушка которую я любил которой я ничего не сказал о своей любви и так как мне шел 22 год то казалось что я остался один на белом свет и  что если не случится какого-то чуда мне уже и жить то незачем.

Я расставила таким образом:

> ​Было тяжело: сестра умерла и уехала девушка, которую я любил, которой я ничего не сказал о своей любви, и так как мне шел 22 год, то казалось, что я остался один на белом свет и  что если не случится какого-то чуда, мне уже и жить то незачем.

Answer (score 1):

Текст желательно разделить на два или три  предложения, в таком виде прочитать его сложно. Кроме того, не очень ясен смысл сообщения о возрасте героя: он как-то связан с его чувствами  или это попутное сообщение?

Попробую предложить следующий вариант:

Было тяжело:сестра умерла и уехала девушка,которую я любил,которой я ничего не сказал о своей любви.  Мне тогда шел 22 год, и мое душевное состояние было близко к отчаянию. Мне казалось,что я остался один на белом свете и что, если не случится какого-то чуда, мне уже и жить-то незачем.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, тут получилась тавтология: "...которую я любил, которой я ничего не сказал..." Проще было сказать: "Уехала моя любимая девушка" или "...которую я любил, а я так и не сказал ей о своей любви".